# WatchKit - Detecting force touch and bypassing context menu

Tags: watchkit

Is it possible to not show a context menu when the user performs a force touch. And instead show a custom interface controller modally.

Or is it even possible to programmatically detect a force touch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to detect a force touch.  You can only show a menu on the force touch.

From an Apple dev evangelist on https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254831?start=0&tstart=0

> There is no API to directly respond to a Force Touch. Performing a
>   Force Touch within a WatchKit app will display the menu (if there is
>   one) for the visible WKInterfaceController.